# Fill sparse row of a dataframe with the existing values in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, fill

I have a dataframe of the following types:

```
CurrentDf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
                   columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
1  7  0  0  0  1  0  2  0  0  0   0
2  8  0  0  0  1  0  3  0  0  0   0
3  7  0  1  0  4  0  0  0  0  0   0
4  5  0  1  0  5  0  0  0  0  0   0
5  5  1  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

and I would like to transform it in this one:

```
DesiredDf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0], [7, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
                   columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  5  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0
1  7  0  0  0  1  1  2  2  0  0   0
2  8  0  0  0  1  1  3  3  3  0   0
3  7  0  1  1  4  4  4  4  0  0   0
4  5  0  1  1  5  5  0  0  0  0   0
5  5  1  1  1  3  3  0  0  0  0   0
```

For each row, the next column take the value of the previous column if the next column is zero, 'till the column number which is given in the column 0.

Comment: it solves the first question I have asked, however I realized that the problem is a bit more complicated and I have updated my question

Comment: Then say this thing below the answer so that the answerer can give their opinion to you :), well question in SO are asked one at a time, so you can make another question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NaNs` are easier to work with than 0s:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.ffill(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  0  0  0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  2  2  2  2
3  0  0  1  1  2  2
4  2  1  1  3  3  3
5  0  0  2  2  5  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, however I realized that the task is a little bit more complex. I have updated my question consequently.